# install conda on windows with conda or pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, pytorch, conda

I am trying to install pytorch on my window.

First, I get command `conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch`from [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

```
(PyTorch Build:Stable(1.3);Your OS:Windows;Package:Conda;Language:Python3.6;CUDA:None), there are some problems described as followings:
**(python36) C:\Users\li_dan0109>conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - pytorch
Current channels:
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-32
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to
    https://anaconda.org
and use the search bar at the top of the page.**
```

Then I also switch pip install by the command `pip3 install torch==1.3.1+cpu torchvision==0.4.2+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html` Then I met this error:

```
**(python36) C:\Users\li_dan0109>pip3 install torch==1.3.1+cpu torchvision==0.4.2+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.3.1+cpu (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.3.1+cpu**
```

I really don't know how to fix it, please help me and thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

To install pytorch follow these two steps.

First of all run this command

```
C:\Users\User>conda install PyTorch -c PyTorch
```

then run this code

```
C:\Users\User>pip3 install torchvision
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you may have the 32-bit installation of Python, in which case you're issue is this: [#16633](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/16633).

Just be aware, that [pyTorch doesn't work on 32-bit systems](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/windows.html#package-not-found-in-win-32-channel).

Please use Windows and Python 64-bit version.